# How to reverse the nested lists and save them in a variable?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, nested

I'm trying to create a program that generates a soccer league schedule. So, that means that the second half of the schedule is the same as the first half, but only the home playing teams are different.

For example:

```
Round 1:
Team A - Team B
Team C - Team D
```

And then, when everyone played against each other, the opposite matches:

```
Team B - Team A
Team D - Team C
```

I'm using a `List<List<List<Team>>>` . You can read it like: A list with rounds with matches with two teams. So:

`List<Team>` is a list of two teams, which is the match: Example `[Team A, Team B]`.

`List<List<Team>>` is a list with matches (so, one rond). Example: `[[Team A, Team B], [Team C, Team D]]`

`List<List<List<Team>>>` is a list with all the rounds. You know what the example should look like.

I have 12 teams, so that are 22 rounds. I have the first 11 rounds in a list called `first11Rounds`. I want to save this in a new list of the same type: `first`:

```
List<List<List<Team>>> first = first11Rounds;
```

For the second half of the schedule, I need the same rounds and matches, but then home and away switched. To achieve this, I'm using:

```
List<List<List<Team>>> first = first11Rounds;

for(List<List<Team>> round : first11Rounds){
    for(List<Team> match : round){
        Collections.reverse(match);
    }
}

List<List<List<Team>>> second = first11Rounds;
```

So, `first` is the original `first11Rounds` variable, and `second` is the adjusted `first11Rounds` variable. However... When I print `first` and `second`, they are exactly the same. Home and away didn't exchange. I really don't understand why. Does anyone have an idea, or a better solution?

Comment: FYI: Have you considered simplifying all that by writing classes for the concepts *match*, *round*, *tournament*? It would make things easier to understand and debug.

Comment: You need to clone all the list so when you reverse them you dont change the original list

Comment: its better you first divide your List<List<List... to normal models that would make it easier to understand example Round has List of matches and Match has Pair of team or 2 teams in general next you can traverse each round which would give you match 1 and match 2 next from match 1 take your team A and put it in match 2 with Team D and vice versa take the replaced Team C to match 1 with Team B